# width for the Highcharts/Highstock Export

Tags: phantomjs, highcharts

On the doc, http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview, width is one POST parameter for the Highcharts Export Server. What are the relationships between this width and [exporting.sourceWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.sourceWidth),  [chart.width](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.width)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the overview noted, you can manually set two different sets of dimensions (width and height) for your chart as it renders on the screen or viewport, and for when it's exported as a PNG, JPEG, SVG, etc. This is useful for when you have extra information or details in the rendered chart that you don't want to show up in the exported version, or vice versa.

If you set a value for `chart.width` and do not specify `exporting.sourceWidth`, the exported versions will be set to the value of `chart.width`.

If you set a value for `chart.width` and also specify a value for `exporting.sourceWidth`, the exported versions will use the value of `exporting.sourceWidth`.

Comment: thanks, but what does **width** in the POST parameters for the Highcharts Export Server mean (in the section Description of POST parameters for the Highcharts Export Server)?

Comment: It should be whatever you've explicitly set in your chart: either 'chart.width' or 'exporting.sourceWidth'.

Comment: If I specified exporting.sourceWidth and width (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside), which one will be used to set the exported PNG width?

Comment: exporting.sourceWidth will be the one used if you specified both.